# Firebase Checkout Timer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, e-commerce

Is there a way to have a checkout timer on my site which is enforced somehow by Firebase?

Lets say I have 3 products left, and if a customer adds 2 into their cart and click on checkout, a request is sent to Firebase to reduce the "stock left" to 1. How can I setup a timer on server-side to enforce the 15 minutes I give the customer to checkout, to ensure that if the customer just closes the tab that Firebase adds those items back to the "stock left" once the 15 minutes expire.

I thought about using a Cloud Function, but the function will run for 15 minutes every time someone buys something since an active timer counts as compute time, which will run up a huge bill.

Can I create a custom authentication token which expires in 15 minutes which is linked to the "reservation" (by having something like a reservation list) and then a query on any new client's side which reduces the "stock left" amount with *active* custom tokens, that way showing an amount in "stock" which does not include expired tokens?

But this might create issues since any user will then have read access to a list of authentication tokens...

Or is there a very simple solution that I am just not seeing?

The ideal situation would be something like an authentication token linked to the product "reservation" since a user will then be unable to visit that link later and complete a purchase since the token will be expired. But I don't know if something like this exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking of it as a timer, I recommend storing the time until the item is held in the database, e.g. in a `heldUntil` field.

The client can still use this value to show a countdown timer, but the information itself is static. So you can program logic quite easily to ignore the hold on the item if the `heldUntil` is before the current time.